# How can I format a json file into a bash environment variable?

Tags: json, bash, shell, printf, xargs

I'm trying to take the contents of a config file (JSON format), strip out extraneous new lines and spaces to be concise and then assign it to an environment variable before starting my application.

This is where I've got so far:

```
pwr_config=`echo "console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(process.argv[2], 'utf-8'))));" | node - config.json | xargs -0 printf '%q\n'` npm run start
```

This pipes a short node.js app into the node runtime taking an argument of the file name and it parses and stringifies the JSON file to validate it and remove any unnecessary whitespace. So far so good.

The result of this is then piped to printf, or at least it would be but printf doesn't support input in this way, apparently, so I'm using xargs to pass it in in a way it supports.

I'm using the %q formatter to format the string escaping any characters that would be a problem as part of a command, but when calling printf through xargs, printf claims it doesn't support %q. I think this is perhaps because there is more than one version of printf but I'm not exactly sure how to resolve that.

Any help would be appreciated, even if the solution is completely different from what I've started :) Thanks!

**Update**
Here's the output I get on MacOS:

```
$ cat config.json | xargs -0 printf %q
printf: illegal format character q
```

My JSON file looks like this:

```
{
    "hue_host": "192.168.1.2",
    "hue_username": "myUsername",
    "port": 12000,
    "player_group_config": [
        {
            "name": "Family Room",
            "player_uuid": "ATVUID",
            "hue_group": "3",
            "on_events": ["media.play", "media.resume"],
            "off_events": ["media.stop", "media.pause"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Lounge",
            "player_uuid": "STVUID",
            "hue_group": "1",
            "on_events": ["media.play", "media.resume"],
            "off_events": ["media.stop", "media.pause"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `cat file.json | xargs -0 printf %q` works for me on debian9. Can you provide some more info and some example output from the pipe prior to the xargs command?

Comment: Post your JSON content and show us the exact output needed. Use `jq`

Comment: Thanks for the help! Question edited to include the information requested. The desired output is the JSON file squashed into an environment config string as part of the command I want to run to execute my script...

Comment: Try `xargs -0 bash -c printf %q` - maybe `printf` is only available as a shell builtin on your system.

Comment: `foo=$(jq -c . config.json)`?

Comment: The lack of the `%q` format specifier fo `printf` indicates an older version of Bash.

Comment: `xargs printf` will run /usr/bin/printf, not the bash builtin version (because `printf` is not being executed by bash, it's being executed by `xargs`), and the /usr/bin version doesn't normally support the `%q` format.

Comment: Why do you need to quote anything in the JSON output using `printf`? It's either already quoted properly according to JSON rules, or it's not - in either case quoting according to shell rules will just garble it.

Comment: @cxw thanks, this looks like it should work but when I do `bash -c` I run into problems with `printf`:
```
$ bash -c printf %q "Hello world"
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
```

Comment: @MarkStickley Sorry - forgot the quotes - use `bash -c 'printf "%q" "Hello"'` with the whole command after `-c` wrapped in quotes, here `''`.  `-c` only uses the immediately following argument as the command, so the whole command needs to be quoted so it is parsed as one argument.  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting

Comment: @Shawn this does exactly what I want it to, thank you, although can't guarantee the availability of jq :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Use `xargs` to pick up `bash`'s `printf` builtin instead of the `printf(1)` executable, probably in `/usr/bin/printf`(thanks to @GordonDavisson):

   ```
   pwr_config=`echo "console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(process.argv[2], 'utf-8'))));" | node - config.json | xargs -0 bash -c 'printf "%q\n"'` npm run start
   ```
2. Simpler: you don't have to escape the output of a command if you quote it.  In the same way that `echo "<|>"` is OK in `bash`, this should also work:

   ```
   pwr_config="$(echo "console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(process.argv[2], 'utf-8'))));" | node - config.json )" npm run start
   ```

   This uses the newer `$(...)` form instead of `` `...` ``, and so the result of the command is a single word stored as-is into the `pwr_config` variable.<sup>*</sup>
3. Even simpler: if your `npm run start` script cares about the whitespace in your JSON, it's fundamentally broken :) .  Just do:

   ```
   pwr_config="$(< config.json)" npm run start
   ```

   The `$(<...)` returns the contents of `config.json`.  They are all stored as a single word (`""`) into `pwr_config`, newlines and all.<sup>*</sup>  If something breaks, either `config.json` has an error and should be fixed, or the code you're running has an error and needs to be fixed.

<sup>* You actually don't need the `""` around `$()`.  E.g., `foo=$(echo a b c)` and `foo="$(echo a b c)"` have the same effect.  However, I like to include the `""` to remind myself that I am specifically asking for all the text to be kept together.</sup>

Comment: Wow thanks so much for the answer and the massive simplification! That's perfect :D